# Not understanding ko.obseravables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So consider the following:

```
(function($, ko){
    var ViewModel = function() {
        var self           = this;
        self.errorMessages = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.desigItems    = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.frequencies   = ko.observableArray([]);
    }

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();

    var loadData = function() {
        $.ddcApiGet('/widget/desigs.json', [], function(data) {
            _processLoadedData(data);
        }, viewModel.errorMessages);
    }

    var loadFrequencies = function() {
        $.ddcApiGet('/widget/freqs.json', [], function(data) {
            _processFrequenciesData(data);
        }, viewModel.errorMessages);
    }

    var _processLoadedData = function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.desig_options.length; i++) {
            viewModel.desigItems.push(data.desig_options[i]);
        }
    }

    var _processFrequenciesData = function(data) {
        var frequencies = [];

        // Get the list of frequencies.
        for (var i = 0; i < data.frequency.length; i++) {
            frequencies.push(data.frequency[i]);
        }

        // Push frequencies on to each of the design items in the list.
        for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.desigItems.length; i++) {
            viewModel.desigItems[i]['frequencies'] = frequencies
        }

        console.log(viewModel.desigItems());
    }

    var preBind = function() {
        loadData();
        loadFrequencies();
    }

    preBind();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#designnation-list-container')[0]);

})(jQuery, ko);
```

Which is then associated with the following view:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<div id="designnation-list-container" data-bind="foreach: desigItems">
<div class="donor-js-wid-desig-opt donor-style-box donor-style-2col">
        <h2 class="donor-js-desig-desc" data-bind="text: desc"> </h2>
        <img class="donor-js-desig-logo donor-style-donation-image" alt="Web Desc 10000 - adding this" src="https://d36vh9gkg2fzwi.cloudfront.net/imageserver/be1b7b8e195587ff422c40750a6caa9f/10000_IPHONE_v1.JPG">

        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="javascript:">

            <input class="donor-js-wid-desig" type="hidden" name="gift_desig" value="10000">

            <p class="donor-js-desig-shorttext" data-bind="html: shortdesc"> </p>
                <p id="donor-js-donation-amount-label">
                    <label class="donor-style-label">Donation Amount</label>
                </p>
            <p>

            <div data-bind="foreach: amount_options">
                <label class="donor-js-amount-choice">
                    <input type="radio" class="donor-js-webware" name="gift_amt" data-bind="attr: {value: desc}, checked: selected"><span class="donor-js-currency-symbol">$</span>&nbsp;<span class="donor-js-amount" data-bind="text: desc"></span>&nbsp;<span class="donor-js-input-currency"></span><br>
                </label>
            </div>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" class="donor-js-other-amount-opt" name="gift_amt" value="other">
                <span id="donor-js-other-label">Amount:</span>
                <span class="donor-js-currency-symbol">$</span></label>
                <input class="donor-js-other-amount-input" type="text" name="other_amt" onclick="$(this).closest('form').find('input[class=donor-js-other-amount-opt]').attr('checked', true);">&nbsp;<span class="donor-js-input-currency"></span>
            </p>

            <p>
                <select class="donor-js-wid-frequency" name="gift_freq" data-bind="options: frequencies, optionsText: desc, value: desc"></select>
            </p>

            <p id="donor-js-gift-notes" style="display:none">
                <label class="donor-js-gift-note-label">Gift Notes
                    <textarea name="gift_note" class="donor-style-select" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea>
                </label>
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" class="donor-js-dona-submit button" value="Add to Cart"><input type="button" class="donor-js-desig-info donor-style-buttonlink" value="show more details">
            </p></form>
        <div class="donor-style-clearb"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Its a lot to take in I know but I am having issues with one specific function: `_processFrequenciesData`

See the issue is that I have a select element:

```
        <p>
            <select class="donor-js-wid-frequency" name="gift_freq" data-bind="options: frequencies, optionsText: desc, value: desc"></select>
        </p>
```

As you may see from the initial view I posted, this select element is inside a loop that loops over the `self.desigItems`

There is a `console.log` in this function (`_processFrequenciesData`) but it returns: `[]`

Which you would think, ok maybe the data isn't fetched, accept it is at this point, because 7 items get rendered to the screen.

What I am trying to do is say, ok: add this list of `frequencies` to each of the `desigItems`

So why is it when I `console.log(viewModel.desigItems)` I get an empty array back, yet when the view walks over the desigItems, I get seven things back?

Comment: Is `$.ddcApiGet()` based on a jQuery Ajax method, by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `observableArray` is not an array. It is a function (!) that *wraps* an array (just as an `observable` is not a value, but a function that wraps a value). To retrieve the actual value an observable must be called:

```
// Push frequencies on to each of the design items in the list.

var desigItems = viewModel.desigItems(); // access the underlying array
for (var i = 0; i < desigItems.length; i++) {
    desigItems[i].frequency = frequencies[i];
}
viewModel.desigItems.notifySubscribers();
console.log(viewModel.desigItems());
```

What you did was adding properties to the observable itself, but that does not affect the value the observable contains.

Now, since we have changed the underlying value of `viewModel.desigItems` without giving knockout a chance to notice, we must call `notifySubscribers()` to inform everyone that the observable has changed.

---

That being said, I would rewrite your entire code like so:

```
(function($, ko){
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.errorMessages = ko.observableArray();
        self.desigItems    = ko.observableArray();
        self.frequencies   = ko.observableArray();
    }

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();

    $(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#designnation-list-container')[0]);
    });

    var desigsReq = $.ddcApiGet('/widget/desigs.json').done(viewModel.desigItems);
    var freqsReq = $.ddcApiGet('/widget/freqs.json').done(viewModel.frequencies);

    $.when(desigsReq, freqsReq).done(function (desigs, freqs) {
        desigs.forEach(function (desig, i) {
            desig.frequency = freqs[i];
        });
    }).fail(viewModel.errorMessages);

})(jQuery, ko);
```

This fixes two timing issues in your code:

- You can't bind a viewmodel before the document is ready.
- You must wait for both Ajax requests to finish before you can combine the results.

Whether it's actually *useful* to combine the two arrays in this manner is a different matter. I'd say it's not a very clean solution to begin with.

---

P.S.: You really could have made this question shorter, virtually none of the code you have posted has anything to do with the issue at hand.

Comment: The OP actually *is* calling the observable array function: `console.log(viewModel.desigItems())`

Comment: Sure he was, but not here: `viewModel.desigItems[i]` (a few lines above)

Comment: Ah, I just focused on the console output thing. Didn't even see that!

Answer (score 1):

> So why is it when I `console.log(viewModel.desigItems())` I get an empty array back, yet when the view walks over the desigItems, I get seven things back?

You have the `console.log(viewModel.desigItems)` call inside the `_processFrequenciesData` callback function.

However, you do not populate `viewModel.desigItems` there - it's populated in the `_processLoadedData` callback function instead.

That might be a simple error. You might just want to move that `console.log(...)` into the other callback.

The way it is now, you will have an empty console output (as you are seeing) when the response for `loadFrequencies` is processed before the response for `loadData`.

Comment: But as you cam see I am trying to add items on to the `desigItems` observable array AFTER its been populated, is there something I should be doing to make that happen